# Schema loads in Pentaho BI Server 5 but cube is not displayed

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

im running schema-workbench 3.6.1, Pentaho BI server 5.0.1, Saiku analytics installed from the marketplace and I successfully publish from schema-workbench. (I also have the datasource present and working in both schema-workbench and BI Server)
When I go to BI server the analytics file created by the workbench is present but the cube is not in saiku analytics, I try to refresh and only are present the two test cubes. What im doing wrong?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pentaho.log and catalina.out files, there's most likely an error on the schema (bad column or table name, wrong data type on a level, or something similar).